# The probability of random walk

Tags: probability

A person starts to walk from **x=0**, and wonders aimlessly along a path by going forward 1 step and backward 1 step with equal probabilities. He took **100** steps.
Find the distribution of the man's place.
the answer says: **X**- the man's place. **Y**-the number of steps forward. Thus **Y~Bin(100,0.5)** then **X=2Y-100** so **P(X=k)=P(Y=(k+100)/2)**. May you explain why **X=2Y-100** so **P(X=k)=P(Y=(k+100)/2)**?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If he takes $Y$ steps forwards, he must have taken $100-Y$ steps backwards. Therefore his $X$ position is $Y-(100-Y)=2Y-100$.

If $X=k$, then $k=2Y-100$, so $Y=\dfrac{k+100}{2}$.

Comment: Thanks a lot! But why **P(X)=P(Y)**?

Comment: it doesn't - the probability that X=k is the same as the probability that Y=(k+100)/2

Comment: k must be even, so P(X=2j)=P(Y=(j+50))